# How to execute JavaScript of Content page while using Update panel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

How to execute JavaScript of Content page while using **Update panel** ?

something i found after browsing for answer is this.

Instead of putting your jQuery code inside of `$(document).ready()`, put it inside

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) { 

}
```

but i don't understand that? and My requirement is within the content page!

Answer (score 0):

just put your javascripts code in **UpdatePanel**

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

         <!-- your code -->

        <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("a").on("click",  function () {
                alert("it's work!");
            });

        });


      </script>

   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```